Security Patch from 2.4.5-p8 to 2.4.5-p9 may break customer API
After applying the patch upgrade 2.4.5-p9 tests for the customer API no longer run properly.
When updating a customer we get
{
"message": "The %fieldName value is invalid. Set the correct value and try again.",
"parameters": {
"fieldName": "default_billing"
}

This seems to be related with the issue 38878.
The change from 2.4.7 slipped into the security patch.
So it seems to be a known issue in 2.4.7 already, and now in the security patch.
Is it safe to revert the patch after applying the security update, or is this change actually important?
